# iOS to android conversion for nsdictionary for http communication

Tags: android, ios

I have following code in ios app, i am converting them to android.

```
NSDictionary *data1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier],@"deviceUid",@"iPhone",@"deviceType",deviceToken,@"deviceToken", nil];

NSDictionary *data2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:_emailTextField.text,@"email",_passwordTextField.text,@"password",device_data,@"deviceModel", nil];
```

Now this data2 is passed to https request for verification

```
parameters:data2
```

But when i try to convert the same code into android I got confused. how data2 will store data1 in android

server receive data in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Try HashMap

```
Map  map =  new HashMap();
map.put("key","Obj");
map.put("secondkey","secondObj");
map.put("thirdkey","thirdObj");
```

Check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/) for Map to JSON conversion.

Comment: and can i pass this to httpclient also... because my biggest confusion  is how JSON will be created using NSDictionary for data1 into data2..

Comment: Check this link. check the second example.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Edited my answer, Please have a look.